# How to activate CORS for a JSON file which is on same server?

Tags: javascript, html, json, cors

On my website, I do have a JS which makes a call to a JSON which is also located on the same server. Local it works very well, but if I change it to my public domain, it doesn't - the CORS problem occurs.

So I would like to implement cors that this works, but unfortunately, it doesnt work...

**.htaccess**

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.My-Domain.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
```

**JS:**

```
return doXHR('https://My-Domain.com/json/data.json', function(err, JsonRespond) {
    if (err) {
        //failed
    }

console.log(JsonRespond);
```

Comment: What headers are returned when trying to access the file? Also, not that you access the file via HTTP while specifying HTTPS in the htaccess file, which might be the culprit

Comment: You mean, what headers are returned when I trying to access the file over URL? In that case it works... (regarding https, sorry this was a mistake by me while posting this question.)

Answer (score 0):

try this code, if the domain is not properly validated, its a security threat.
Refer: [Source Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Sender side:

```
targetWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
```

Receiver side:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event)
 {
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
  return;
  // ...
 }
```

Comment: All the stuff (html, json, js etc.) is running on the same server. And where should I put the code in `sender side` and where the `receiver side` - i mean i want to call / get content of a JSON file not a website?

Comment: running same server with different domain name, this causes the CORS exception. source domain which sends request to destination domain which process the request.

Comment: yeah, but the domain name is also the same. there is no difference. Only difference is the location of the JSON file, which is in a subfolder.